# how to push UIViewController from UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

So basically, how can I push a UIViewController from a UITableView. 
I have an array of contents on the TableView I need to tap inside the content and get the ViewController as result.
I tried making a `- (IBAction)PushViewController:(id)sender` but I can't reference the TableView.

Yes, i'm noob... ):

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set a UITableViewDelegate for your table view, tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath: will get called when someone taps on a cell.  At that point you can push another controller, optionally telling it what to display.